# adjusting the values of an atom which is made up of a list of refs

Tags: clojure, refs

I have an atom which is to contain a list of refs. How would I update the list of refs inside the atom? I tried the following but it does not work.

```
(def theatom (atom []))
(def mylist [1 2 3 4])

(reset! theatom (map ref mylist))

(swap! theatom (fn [anAtom]
    (map (fn [theRef] (dosync (alter theRef inc))) theatom)
    ))
(println (map deref @theatom))
```

The idea is to increase each ref value by one.
I should then print [2 3 4 5].

Comment: Please indicate what the errors are from the start. I'm fairly certain I know what's wrong, so I posted an answer. It's always good to have all the information though.

Comment: This is just a typo. Change `(map (fn [theRef] (dosync (alter theRef inc))) theatom)` to `(map (fn [theRef] (dosync (alter theRef inc))) anAtom)`, (then change that parameter to something like `refs`, since it isn't an atom. Also, are you sure you need `ref`s at all here?

Comment: After your suggested change, I get the error:  ./clj tests.clj 
(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Future,

Comment: I undeleted my answer. The second error was because of you calling `(map deref @theatom)` because you're returning the numbers from `dosync`, which was unwrapping the `ref`. Again though, are you *sure* you need `ref`s here?

Comment: I need to work with refs because I need to do transactions with the contents of the atom. I am working with a larger piece of code but I cannot seem to have an idea of how to adjust those refs inside the atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it set up weird. I think you meant:

```
(swap! theatom (fn [refs]
                 (map (fn [theRef]
                        (dosync (alter theRef inc))
                        theRef) ; Returning the return of dosync "unwraps" the refs
                      refs)))
```

Although it could be made a little neater using `doseq`:

```
(swap! theatom (fn [refs]
                 (doseq [r refs]
                   (dosync (alter r inc)))
                 refs))
```

You were trying to map over the atom instead of the list it holds. Atoms aren't iterable, so that would have raised an error.